# Why encoding doesn't work in function?

Tags: php, regex, function, encoding, character-encoding

I have a function for clean an input (delete trim, special caractere and number) in specific file and an index who i call this function.

```
// In index.php
$input = format_input($_POST['name']);

// In inc/function.php
function format_input($input){
    $pattern = '/[^a-zA-ZÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåÒÓÔÕÖØòóôõöøÈÉÊËèéêëÇçÌÍÎÏìíîïÙÚÛÜùúûüÿÑñ\-\'\s]/';
    $output = preg_replace($pattern, "", $input);
    $output = trim($output);
    $output = ucfirst(strtolower($output));
    return $output;
}
```

if i use this function in my index, the encoding is OK, but if i use a call to this in another file, i have black losange on my regex.

the file are in utf-8 both, i don't understand why doesn't work !

Comment: What type of call?

Comment: Did you check if really **all** the files you are working in are encoded in UTF-8? Alternatively, you can use the \u0000 notation to list your characters. This will also work in non-UTF-8 files.

Comment: Dainis Abols : " $input = format_input($_POST['name']); "

ssc-hrep3 : Yes they are :(

Comment: ⧫⧫ not seeing the 'black losange'.  ⧫⧫

Comment: Do you mean this will happen on the same input string?!

Comment: If I var_dump my pattern in the file (inc/function.php) this display something like : /[^a-zA-Z⧫⧫⧫⧫⧫⧫⧫⧫⧫⧫⧫⧫⧫⧫⧫⧫⧫⧫⧫⧫⧫⧫⧫⧫⧫⧫⧫⧫\-\'\s]/ .

My input string is correctly encoded (I see éèà if i write éèà)

Comment: Maybe HTML output charset? `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: this meta is already in code ;) I think i must serialize and deserialize the data, but i haven't test yet

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$output = ucfirst(mb_strtolower($output,'utf-8'));
```

instead of:

```
$output = ucfirst(strtolower($output));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php